# Filter IDictionary(Of TK, TV) to an IDictionary(Of TK, TV) with linq

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-objects

Something very basic seems to be escaping me.

```
Dim foo As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
foo.Add("key", Nothing)
foo.Add("key2", "something")
```

I wish to get a IDictiorany(Of String, String) back, with only elements that have a non empty value.  I thought this would do it:

```
foo.Where(Function(x) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Value))
```

But that ends up being the wrong type.  Adding:

```
.ToDictionary(Function(x) x.Key)
```

Doesn't help any either.  Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah... Answered my own question.  Will leave this up just in case it is of any use to someone else.

```
Dim foo As Dictionary(Of String, String)
foo.Add("k1", Nothing)
foo.Add("k2", "something")

Dim IDictionary(Of String, String) res = foo _
    .Where(Function(x) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Value)) _
    .ToDictionary(Function(x) x.Key, Function(y) y.Value)
```

Comment: Are you creating and filtering the dictionary in the same scope? If you are, you can use an anonymous type for the creation, which makes filtering and turning it into a dictionary much cleaner.